# How to pass res_id:

Tags: odoo-12

I have a button in my form view from which a pop up window is open for a particular employee..on this pop up window.. i have a new button for employee salary detail. which brings detail about salary of employee on line level...but when i open pop up window and make some inputs and confirm it..this record is not saving.. i also pass res_id : self.id.

please help me..[This is the pop up window which is opening from button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P7Wcr.png)

Comment: Please provide examples and code :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `active_ids` to get the current employee then call the `write` method to save the edited fields.

```
employees = self.env['hr.employee'].browse(self.env.context.get('active_ids'))
employees.write({'name': self.name, ..})
```

Comment: Hello, thank your reply..this is not working for me...can you explain please?

Comment: Execute the code when you confrm your changes in the wizard.

Comment: Is your issue saving head details list?